# %%A was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to zip a folder containing files. So inorder to do that i need to loop through the entire file list and execute 7za command. (7zip command line version)

```
for /f %%A in ('"G:\Files Sample\zip\txt\*.t
xt"') do 7za -tzip "%%A.zip" "%%A"
```

However windows says that this command is not valid.

Error message is

```
%%A was unexpected at this time
```

How do i overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`%%A` is used when you use a batch program (*.bat)

try remove one `'%'`

Comment: yup that helped, and also there is a point to note, you need to put the dir /b command inside the bracketed region

Comment: Also one should note that you can't use something like %file it seems. Only single letter seems to be allowed for parameter.

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing it from the command line, you don't have to escape the %, so `%a` is sufficient. You only need to use `%%a` from batch files.

Also, you wanna be selecting the files instead of executing "G:\Files Sample\zip\txt\*.txt" as a command, which is what the `/f` switch does in combination with single quotes. The full command would be: `for %A in ("G:\Files Sample\zip\txt\*.txt") do 7za -tzip "%A.zip" "%A"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a batch file.

```
FOR "G:\Files Sample\zip\txt\" %%G IN (*.txt) DO  7za -tzip "%%G.zip" "%%G"
```

Add `/R` as option to search for the files in all subfolder.

A good explanation of cmd- methods you could find at [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/)