# how to get yesterday's date in a batch file

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

I know how to get today's date in Windows 7. here is the command that I am using:

```
%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%
```

But I want to get yesterday, I do not know how.

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentmath.php

Comment: 1st link when googling date subtraction batch file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-dos-scripting

Comment: since it's w7, why not use tools available:  `powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%Y%m%d"`

Comment: @wmz as for me (win 8.1) better use `powershell get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat '%Y-%m-%d'` - date format parameters in single quote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get 3 days past date from current date Using Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191084/how-to-get-3-days-past-date-from-current-date-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 17):

If you're limited to *just* `cmd.exe`, then the other solutions, despite their size, are probably as good as you'll get. However, modern Windows (such as your Win7) ships with quite a few *other* tools which can do the job far easier.

Just create a VBScript `yester.vbs` script as follows:

```
d = date() - 1
wscript.echo year(d) * 10000 + month(d) * 100 + day(d)
```

Then you can call it from your `cmd` script with:

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yester.vbs') do set yesterday=%%a
```

and the `yesterday` variable will be created in the form `yyyymmdd` for you to manipulate however you desire.

Comment: **Comment 1:** Make sure that C:\Windows\System32 is in your PATH, otherwise it will throw an error: `'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command.`
This can be solved by replacing `cscript` by `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe"` in the `for.....`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976872/cscript-is-not-recognized-inside-a-batch

Comment: **Comment 2:** If you want to execute `for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yester.vbs') do set yesterday=%%a` directly in the `cmd` terminal, you should replace the `%%` by `%`, otherwise you will get the following error message: `%%A was unexpected at this time`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311562/a-was-unexpected-at-this-time

Comment: Jeje, I believe system32 is in the path by default. If someone has removed it, it's on them to fix the issue - I assume someone actively removing it will know the consequences. On the double-percent comment, you raise a good point but the question explicitly stated 'in a batch file'.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry the comments are not really aiming at your answer (which I +1 btw) but are here to help people who encountered problems like me while implementing it ;)

Answer (score 9):

Found a script that will work to ensure you get the previous day even if the year or month changes [Dos Yesterday Batch](http://www.powercram.com/2010/07/get-yesterdays-date-in-ms-dos-batch.html).

```
@echo off

set yyyy=

set $tok=1-3
for /f "tokens=1 delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do set $d1=%%u
if "%$d1:~0,1%" GTR "9" set $tok=2-4
for /f "tokens=%$tok% delims=.:/-, " %%u in ('date /t') do (
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=/-,()." %%x in ('echo.^|date') do (
set %%x=%%u
set %%y=%%v
set %%z=%%w
set $d1=
set $tok=))

if "%yyyy%"=="" set yyyy=%yy%
if /I %yyyy% LSS 100 set /A yyyy=2000 + 1%yyyy% - 100

set CurDate=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%
set dayCnt=%1

if "%dayCnt%"=="" set dayCnt=1

REM Substract your days here
set /A dd=1%dd% - 100 - %dayCnt%
set /A mm=1%mm% - 100

:CHKDAY
if /I %dd% GTR 0 goto DONE
set /A mm=%mm% - 1
if /I %mm% GTR 0 goto ADJUSTDAY
set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1

:ADJUSTDAY
if %mm%==1 goto SET31
if %mm%==2 goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 goto SET31
if %mm%==4 goto SET30
if %mm%==5 goto SET31
if %mm%==6 goto SET30
if %mm%==7 goto SET31
if %mm%==8 goto SET31
if %mm%==9 goto SET30
if %mm%==10 goto SET31
if %mm%==11 goto SET30
REM ** Month 12 falls through

:SET31
set /A dd=31 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET30
set /A dd=30 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:LEAPCHK
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4
if not %tt%==0 goto SET28
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100
if not %tt%==0 goto SET29
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400
if %tt%==0 goto SET29

:SET28
set /A dd=28 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:SET29
set /A dd=29 + %dd%
goto CHKDAY

:DONE
if /I %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%
if /I %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%

REM Set IIS and AWS date variables
set IISDT=%yyyy:~2,2%%mm%%dd%
set AWSDT=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
:: Strip the day of the week from the current date
FOR %%A IN (%Date%) DO SET Today=%%A
:: Parse the date, prefix day and month with an extra leading zero
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%A IN ("%Today%") DO (
    SET Day=0%%A
    SET Month=0%%B
    SET Year=%%C
)
:: Remove excess leading zeroes
SET Day=%Day:~-2%
SET Month=%Month:~-2%
:: Display the results
SET Day
SET Month
SET Year
:: Convert to Julian date
CALL :JDate %Year% %Month% %Day%
:: Display the result
SET JDate
:: Subtract 1 day
SET /A JPast = JDate - 1
:: Display the result
SET JPast
:: Convert back to "normal" date again
CALL :GDate %JPast%
:: Display the result
::SET GDate=20130121
SET GDate

echo The previous day in form YYYYMMDD is %GDate%

pause
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

GOTO:EOF

:JDate
:: Convert date to Julian
:: Arguments : YYYY MM DD
:: Returns   : Julian date
::
:: First strip leading zeroes
SET MM=%2
SET DD=%3
IF %MM:~0,1% EQU 0 SET MM=%MM:~1%
IF %DD:~0,1% EQU 0 SET DD=%DD:~1%
::
:: Algorithm based on Fliegel-Van Flandern
:: algorithm from the Astronomical Almanac,
:: provided by Doctor Fenton on the Math Forum
:: (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51907.html),
:: and converted to batch code by Ron Bakowski.
SET /A Month1 = ( %MM% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1  = %1 + 4800
SET /A JDate  = 1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MM% - 2 -12 * %      Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DD% - 32075

SET Month1=
SET Year1=
GOTO:EOF
:GDate
:: Convert Julian date back to "normal" Gregorian date
:: Argument : Julian date  
:: Returns  : YYYY MM DD
:: 
:: Algorithm based on Fliegel-Van Flandern
:: algorithm from the Astronomical Almanac,
:: provided by Doctor Fenton on the Math Forum
:: (http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51907.html),
:: and converted to batch code by Ron Bakowski.
::
SET /A P      = %1 + 68569
SET /A Q      = 4 * %P% / 146097
SET /A R      = %P% - ( 146097 * %Q% +3 ) / 4
SET /A S      = 4000 * ( %R% + 1 ) / 1461001
SET /A T      = %R% - 1461 * %S% / 4 + 31
SET /A U      = 80 * %T% / 2447
SET /A V      = %U% / 11
SET /A GYear  = 100 * ( %Q% - 49 ) + %S% + %V%
SET /A GMonth = %U% + 2 - 12 * %V%
SET /A GDay   = %T% - 2447 * %U% / 80
:: Clean up the mess
FOR %%A IN (P Q R S T U V) DO SET %%A=
:: Add leading zeroes
IF 1%GMonth% LSS 20 SET GMonth=0%GMonth%
IF 1%GDay%   LSS 20 SET GDay=0%GDay%
:: Return value
:: Here you can define the form that you want
SET GDate=%GYear%%GMonth%%GDay%
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that creates the earlierday.vbs file on the fly, uses it and deletes it afterwards.

It stores the result in the NewDate variable

This example calculates 1 day ago, but can easily calculate a date further back by changing the value of the Offset variable.

```
@echo off
set Offset=1

echo d = date() - WScript.Arguments.Item(0) > earlierday.vbs
echo wscript.echo year(d) * 10000 + month(d) * 100 + day(d) >> earlierday.vbs

for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo earlierday.vbs %Offset%') do set NewDate=%%a

del earlierday.vbs    
echo %NewDate%
pause
```

You could refine this slightly by using %temp%\earlierday.vbs to create the file in the user's temp folder.

*Credits to **paxdiablo** as this is a simple tweak on his earlier post.*

**EDIT:** Here's something with a loop, close to what I actually need it to do.  This will take 14 days off today's date and return that date.  Then it will keep going back 7 days at a time until it gets to 35 days day ago.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set BackDaysFrom=14
Set BackDaysTo=35
Set BackDaysStep=7

echo d = date() - WScript.Arguments.Item(0) > earlierday.vbs
echo wscript.echo year(d) * 10000 + month(d) * 100 + day(d) >> earlierday.vbs

for /L %%i in (%BackDaysFrom%, %BackDaysStep%, %BackDaysTo%) do (
    for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo earlierday.vbs %%i') do set NewDate=%%a
    echo !NewDate!
)

del earlierday.vbs    

pause
```