# 'cscript' is not recognized inside a batch

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wsh

I need to call a .bat that calls a .vbs. When i run FindDir.vbs from command prompt is ok, but when i try to call it from CallingVbs.bat i got the error message.

'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

The code i'm using to call .vbs  is the same to .bat and to command prompt.

```
cscript FindDir.vbs
```

Both files are in same folder. 
I do not understand why cscript command works in command prompt but not in .bat. Could anyone explain me why it happens?

Thanks

Comment: It must be a typo or something. It works fine when I try it.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `cscript` with `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe"`?

Comment: Did not work, searching in the web found the link in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By mistake i was using a variable with name "path", so cscript stopped working.

[I solve it with this](http://www.videoredo.net/msgBoard/archive/index.php/t-889.html)

Answer (score 4):

Very simply you solve this issue. 
but before that you must ensure the cscript.exe file exist in your C:\Windows\System32 path. then,

%SystemRoot%\System32\then your command line

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have **cscript.exe** in System32 folder.

Then click on environment variables button in Control Panel -> System -> advanced tab and add environment variable `PATH` with `C:\Windows\System32` as value.

If you have already a `PATH` variable just add the same value with a semicolon: `;C:\Windows\System32`.