# How can I create a date stamp for yesterday

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to acquire the contents of the file with a datestamp in the file name for yesterday (WH.FBTBT20130214.csv).  I created a date stamp variable for today but cannot find anything in google that tells me how to backdate my datestamp one day utilizing the same format.  Here is the code that I created in my batch file:

```
@echo off

REM ***** 20130215 MS Define DateStamp variable *****
Set DateStamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
Set DateStamp=%DateStamp%
REM Set DateStamp=20130212

echo DateStamp: %DateStamp%
```

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date arithmetic in dos scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-dos-scripting)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891335/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-dos. I imagine there are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't always just subtract 1 from the date and get yesterday's date.  Say it's March 1.  What's yesterday?  March 0?  Doesn't work that way.  A better way is to use vbscript's `Date()` object and subtract a day from it.

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM ***** 20130215 MS Define DateStamp variable *****
echo d = DateAdd^("d", -1, Date^(^)^)>yesterday.vbs
echo wscript.echo DatePart^("yyyy", d^) ^& "/" ^& DatePart^("m", d^) ^& "/" ^& DatePart^("d", d^)>>yesterday.vbs
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%I in ('cscript /nologo yesterday.vbs') do (
    set Year=%%I
    if %%J LEQ 9 (set Month=0%%J) else set Month=%%J
    if %%K LEQ 9 (set Day=0%%K) else set Day=%%K
)
set DateStamp=%Year%%Month%%Day%
del /q yesterday.vbs
echo %DateStamp%
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I did not realize that was the way BATCH worked.  I appreciate the correction.  I'll try vbscript.  Haven't worked with it in a good while.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Just in case anyone is interested:

Set /A DateStamp=(%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%)-1

echo DateStamp: %DateStamp%

Comment: That will not work. What do you think happens if today's date is January 1, 2014? 20140101 becomes 20140100, but you want 20131231.