# how to make folder name with yesterday's date?

Tags: batch-file

I want to do two things:

- create folder name with yesterday's name - for example if today is 2014_07_18 then create folder name with 2014_07_17 under this directory "d:\test"
- then I have some files with yesterday's date (2014_07_17) as modified date under "d:\test*.txt" which needs to transfer to newly created folder at "d:\test\2014_07_17"

but by running batch code today (2014_07_18)

Comment: And what you tried so far?... can we see your batch file and your aproach. Tell us what is not working in your attemp. [recommend reading](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a date stamp for yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897097/how-can-i-create-a-date-stamp-for-yesterday) for question #1. Once you've got that working, you can put some effort into copying the files, and then [edit] to ask a specific question about problems you're having doing so (and include your code to show your efforts). (As a tip: I found the duplicate by using the search expression `[batch-file] yesterdays date`, including the `[]` around the tag name, searching on this site.) Good luck.

Comment: okay i am using below code to create folder with today's date like 2014_07_18 - BUT - i want to create folder name with yesterday's date by running code today...                                                                                    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
set MyDayOfWeek=%%a
set MyMonth=%%b
set MyDay=%%c
set MyYear=%%d)

f:
mkdir F:\test\%MyYear%_%MyMonth%_%MyDay%

Comment: Do you only create the folder if there are files modified yesterday?  If so, you could the solution for reading a file's modified date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2116420/2540156

Comment: There is a solution here to get yesterdays date into a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796749/re-naming-a-file-name-to-include-yesterdays-date-using-command-prompt/20798129#20798129

Comment: Thanks a lot..."foxidrive" - it helped to create same...i just did add mkdir command into it ...and magic...:-)

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* jsctipt comment 

    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%d in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do (
        set "yesterday=%%d"
    )
    echo %yesterday%
    md %yesterday% >nul 2>&1
    exit /b 0

end of jsccript comment */

var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
var dd = yesterday.getDate();    
var mm = yesterday.getMonth()+1;                    
var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();    
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
yesterday = yyyy+'_'+mm+'_'+dd;

WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(yesterday);
```

save this as `.bat`

Answer (score 0):

This was fun. Below is a brainstorm of how you could get to your goal -- there are some flaws that need to be fixed (they would
also be fun to figure out), such as:

If it's the 1st of the month, you'll need to change the month value (e.g. 08012014 to 07312014). You'll also need to factor in 
months with varying total number of days (e.g. 08012014 to 07312014, 07012014 to 06302014, 03012014 to 02282014).

> C:\example>echo %date%
>
> Sat 08/16/2014
>
> C:\example>echo %date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%
>
> 08162014
>
> C:\example>set /a today=%date:~-7,2%
>
> 16
>   C:\example>set /a yesterday=%today%-1
>
> 15
>
> C:\example>echo %date:~-10,2%%yesterday%%date:~-4,4%
>
> 08152014
>
> C:\example>set ydate=%date:~-10,2%%yesterday%%date:~-4,4%
>
> C:\example>mkdir %ydate%
>
> C:\example>dir
>
> Volume in drive C has no label.
>
> Volume Serial Number is 8E75-333E
>
> Directory of C:\example
>
> 08/16/2014  07:29 PM              .
>
> 08/16/2014  07:29 PM              ..
>
> 08/16/2014  07:29 PM              > > 08152014

```
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           3 Dir(s)  938,853,076,992 bytes free
```

> C:\example>

Comment: 1. `%date%` depends on locate, which is not good. 2. The OP uses YYYY_MM_DD