# Day minus in windows batch file in 2 digit

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bat file which simply generates a date

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set CurrYear=%%c

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set CurrMoth=%%a

for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set CurrDay=%%b


set bDate =01/%CurrMoth%/%CurrYear%

set eDate=%CurrDay%/%CurrMoth%/%CurrYear%

set /a dayminus = %CurrDay% - 1

echo %dayminus%

pause
```

The answer I get for `echo %dayminus%` is 6 instead of 06 & that's my problem.

Comment: What is the goal here? Neither 6 nor 06 are dates. Is the goal to get the date of yesterday?

Comment: Windows batch is pretty deficient in these areas. You might want to try something like Powershell.

Comment: yes thats the goal but the answer should be in 2 digits - for example if its 8 than answer should be 08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to simply ensure a number is left-zero-padded to two places, you can just use:

```
if %dayminus% lss 10 set dayminus=0%dayminus%
```

However, you'll soon run into another problem, specifically what you do when you run this on the first of the month. But that's probably a matter for a separate question (or you could just look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891335/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-dos)).

If you're open to using other tools (which ship with Windows, just like `cmd.exe` does), then VBScript is possibly the easiest option. You can just create a one-liner `yesterdom.vbs`:

```
wscript.echo day(date()-1)
```

and then call it from your script:

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterdom.vbs') do set dayminus=%%a
```

If you don't want the hassle of maintaining the one-liner, you can create and destroy it from within your script, such as with:

```
@echo off
echo wscript.echo day(date()-1) >yesterdom.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterdom.vbs') do set dayminus=%%a
del /q yesterdom.vbs >nul: 2>nul:
echo %dayminus%
```

Comment: thanks but yes you are correct, now i seek an answer on how to take care when the day is 1st of every month.

Comment: @IrfanMemon, follow the link I gave, then you can get it from yesterday's date. That's if you're strictly limited to `cmd.exe`. If you're allowed to use other standard Windows tools, I've added some VBScript which will make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

(Interestingly, most people want to know how to go the other way.) The reason this is happening is because batch considers numbers that begin with a 0 to be octal and then simplifies them to drop the 0 when printing as an integer. You can get around this by treating the variable like a string instead.

```
set /a dayminus=%CurrDay%-1
if %dayminus% lss 10 (
    set dayminus=0%dayminus%
)
echo %dayminus%
```

Comment: thanks but yes you are correct, now i seek an answer on how to take care when the day is 1st of every month.

Comment: @IrfanMemon - Feel free to ask another question after picking an answer (click the check mark next to the answer you want to mark as accepted), but the solution will likely involve a dozen `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick workaround that I have prepared for you in a sample program:

```
@echo off
set /a test = 4
IF %test% lss 10 (
@echo 0%test%
)
@pause
```

This will always get you a two digit number since anything below 10 will have the added 0 in front of it when it's being written to the screen.

Comment: thanks but yes you are correct, now i seek an answer on how to take care when the day is 1st of every month.

Comment: You don't need the `@` on any lines after the initial `@echo off`.

Comment: You don't, but it suppresses the extra information that clutters up your screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Batch file solution that get the date of yesterday; it also works for the current date minus any number of days less than a month:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create array of days per month; both month and day are 100-based
set i=100
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "daysPerMonth[!i!]=1%%a"
)

rem Get today's date parts (from "Dow MM/DD/YYYY" format) - 1 day
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do (
   set /A MM=1%%a, DD=1%%b-1, YYYY=%%c, YYYYmod4=YYYY %% 4
)
if %YYYYmod4% equ 0 set "daysPerMonth[102]=129"

rem Adjust date if previous month
if %DD% equ 100 (
   set /A MM-=1
   if !MM! equ 100 (
      set /A MM=112, YYYY-=1
   )
   set /A DD=daysPerMonth[!MM!]
)

set "dateMinus=%DD:~1%/%MM:~1%/%YYYY%
echo %dateMinus%
```